# wget download only the sub directory

Tags: wget

i need to download only the sub directory named pyVim with all its content ,but i

am getting the parents as well , even that i tried the following options:

```
wget -r   --no-parent http://server/pub/scripts/pyVim
```

getting : server directory with its subdirectories

tried:

```
wget -r  -X pub,scripts --no-parent http://server/pub/scripts/pyVim
```

tried few more options ,none of those works

i just need to download pyVim directory with its content to the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

You said `pyVim` is a directory, but then the URL you passed to `wget` indicates that `pyVim` is a file in the directory `scripts`.

To explicitly tell `wget` that `pvVim` is a directory pass a trailing `/`. So your final command is:

```
wget -r --no-parent http://server/pub/scripts/pyVim/
```

Comment: Note also that `-r`, when applied to an HTTP download, only "recursively" downloads things that are actually linked from the page. Since there is no way in HTTP to expose a "directory listing" for a site that doesn't provide one, if you want to download *every file* (not just those that are linked) in the `/pub/scripts/pyVim` directory, you need to make sure that directory listing (in Apache or whatever HTTP server is in use) is turned on for this directory.

Comment: the answer above was help full, but didn't resolve the issue ,since i am

downloading the "server" directory with its sub-directories

if i am doing :

    wget -r -nH  --no-parent http://server/pub/scripts/pyVim/

i am getting the directory : pub

Comment: Did you make the change as I suggested? The command you've shown still doesn't have the trailing `/` as I asked you to add